What is the difference between a polynomial and a polynomial function?
I recently read a thread on this site, in which a user stated "every polynomial induces a function". It didn't really hit me until now. So I'm wondering: is there actually a difference between a polynomial and the "associated function"?

There is a technical distinction between the two, although arguably the distinction does not matter much if the coefficients of your polynomial come from an infinite field like $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. But the (distinct) polynomials $x+1$ and $x^2+1$ induce the same function over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, for example. A precise definition of "polynomial" can found in various algebra textbooks, e.g. Lang's Algebra. Roughly speaking, a polynomial is a "formal sum" of powers of $x$, with coefficients from a given field; there are various ways of making this definition precise.

Up through (precalculus and) calculus and even analysis, we think of polynomials as functions. However, in abstract algebra it is important to distinguish the notions, as, for example, working with integers mod a prime $p$, the polynomial $f(x)=x^p-x$ takes only the value $0$. But it is certainly not the zero polynomial.

Would you mind citing the thread or the site mentioned in the question?

What is the difference between Kepler's laws and a solar system?

A polynomial is an expression like $3x^2-7x$. Its general form is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k .
$$
A polynomial function is a relation between values (say values of $x$) and other values that are expressed in terms of some polynomial expression defined in terms of $x$. An example would be the function $f$ that associates real numbers to other real numbers according to the rule $f(x) = 3x^2-7x$.

A problem with saying that polynomials are expressions is that $x+x$ and $2x$ are not the same expression, even though we want to think of them as the same polynomial. There are various ways of giving a precise definition to polynomials, but just saying that they are "expressions" does not quite work (even though that's the intuition that motivates the precise definition).

@Joe, note the general form I specified. It has exactly one term for each power of $x$. And I wasn’t trying to provide a formal definition anyway.
